# I get a "project not found" message when I try to use realize as hot reloader

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I'm developing a web app in gin, and I've installed realize as a hot reloading tool.

In my local environment, `realize start` works fine, but when I run it in docker-compose
, it says "project not found" and won't start the server.

```
root@dcdaf6197639:/app# realize start
len [0/0]0x0
[15:37:06][APP] : Watching 14 file/s 14 folder/s
[15:37:06][APP] : Install started
[15:37:07][APP] : Install completed in 0.978 s
[15:37:07][APP] : Running...
[15:37:07][APP] : project not found
[15:37:07][APP] : project not found
```

this is my .realize.yaml

```yaml
settings:
  legacy:
    force: false
    interval: 0s
schema:
- name: app
  path: .
  commands:
    run:
      status: true
  watcher:
    extensions:
    - go
    paths:
    - /
    ignore:
      paths:
      - .git
      - .realize
      - vendor
```

this is my Dockerflie

```
FROM golang:1.14-buster as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download
RUN go get github.com/oxequa/realize
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: bin/bash -c "realize start"
```

I have main.go in the root directory.
I'm having trouble understanding the cause.
Please help me.

Comment: This error is returned here: https://github.com/oxequa/realize/blob/498ce46d1b223185254598c51d88718179abb71e/realize/projects.go#L629
So you probably have problems with `GOBIN` or overwrite it with `p.Tools.Run.Method`

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue, try to edit your ***.realize.yaml*** to :

```
settings:
  legacy:
    force: false
    interval: 0s
schema:
- name: app
  path: .
  commands:
    install:
      status: true
      method: go build -o tmp/app.out main.go
    run:
      status: true
      method: tmp/app.out
  watcher:
    extensions:
    - go
    paths:
    - /
    ignore:
      paths:
      - .git
      - .realize
      - vendor
```

reference link : [gravityblast/issues/#99](https://github.com/gravityblast/fresh/issues/99#issuecomment-549248992)